# Check if record exists: insert if no, display message if yes

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

EDIT: Update! Got the first part working. However, I'm unsure how to also check for the other variables within the same IF() statement. Can anyone help me with that? The single if statement will refuse classes named exactly like the input. However, I need it to also refuse Days AND Times that are equal.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Register Diver</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="php_styles.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type"
    content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Aqua Don's Scuba School</h1>
    <h2>Registration Confirmation</h2>
    <?php
    $DiverID = $_GET['diverID'];
    if (empty($DiverID))
        exit("<p>You must enter a diver ID! Click your browser's Back button to return to the previous page.</p>");
    $DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "students", "password")
        Or die("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>"
        . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_connect_errno()
        . ": " . mysqli_connect_error()) . "</p>";
    $DBName = "scuba_school";
    @mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName)
        Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
        . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
        . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";

    $TableName = "registration";
    $SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM $TableName";
    $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
    if (!$QueryResult) {
        $SQLstring = "CREATE TABLE registration (diverID SMALLINT, class VARCHAR(40), days VARCHAR(40), time VARCHAR(40))";
        $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring)
            Or die("<p>Unable to create the registration table.</p>"
            . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
            . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";
        echo "<p>Successfully created the registration table.</p>";
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    $Class = $_GET['class'];
    $Days = $_GET['days'];
    $Time = $_GET['time'];
    $DiverID = $_GET['diverID'];

    $DBConnect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "students", "password");
    $DBName = "scuba_school";
    @mysqli_select_db($DBConnect, $DBName)
        Or die("<p>Unable to select the database.</p>"
        . "<p>Error code " . mysqli_errno($DBConnect)
        . ": " . mysqli_error($DBConnect)) . "</p>";


    $sqlString= "SELECT * FROM `registration` WHERE `diverID` = $DiverID AND `class` = '$Class' AND `days` = '$Days' AND `time` = '$Time'";
    $QueryResult = mysqli_query($DBConnect, $sqlString) or die("MySQL error: " . mysqli_error($DBConnect) . "<hr>\nQuery: $QueryResult");  
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);

    if ($row["class"] == $Class)
    {

    echo "<p>You are already registered for $Class</p>";
        }

        elseif($row["days"] == $Days && $row["time"] == $Time)
        {
            echo "<p>There is a conflict with $Days or $Time</p>";
            }
    else
    {
     $SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $TableName VALUES('$DiverID', '$Class', '$Days', '$Time')";
        $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
        echo "<p>You are registered for $Class on $Days, $Time. Click your browser's Back button to register for another course or review your schedule.</p>";
    }


    mysqli_close($DBConnect);
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: And what is your problem exactly? Can u clarify it more ?

Comment: I am getting errors and the check is not working.  Whereas before I had the check the code worked fine, just duplicate rows were allowed to be inserted.

I want to stop the duplicate rows from being allowed to get inserted

Comment: so, did you solve your problem?

Comment: @Tivie I have it working for seeing if it's the same class.  But ALSO checking to see if it is the same day AND time is not.  I'm not sure how to include that logical operation on the same line.

Comment: try using datetime instead of string. Each classs has a start datetime and an end datetime. Get all class times from the database and the compare each row to the datetime the user is trying to register. If the time chosen is > (after) start datetime but < (before) end datetime, then it's clashing with another class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE

Just a side note, in PHP, **by convention**, variables start with with a lowercase char in contrast to Classes and Interfaces that start with an uppercase char. Also, read these standards if you wish (PSR). [those are the standards I adopt](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted)

---

### EDIT: I just tested this code with mock up mysql tables and it works as desired. Create the MYSQL tables following the provided schemas. You can use PHPMyAdmin to import the schemas. Copy the FULL CODE to a NEW FILE and run it in the browser. Will work as intended, test it myself.

MYSQL TABLES:

Registration

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Nov 16, 2012 at 11:14 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.24
-- PHP Version: 5.3.15

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `registration`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `registration` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `diverID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `class` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `class` (`class`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `registration`
--

INSERT INTO `registration` (`id`, `diverID`, `class`, `time`) VALUES
(3, 1, 1, '2012-11-18 11:30:00'),
(4, 1, 3, '2012-11-19 17:00:00'),
(13, 2, 1, '2012-11-19 17:00:00');

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `registration`
--
ALTER TABLE `registration`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `registration_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`class`) REFERENCES `classes` (`cid`);

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

---

classes:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.1
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Nov 16, 2012 at 11:16 AM
-- Server version: 5.5.24
-- PHP Version: 5.3.15

SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `classes`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `classes` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `className` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `classes`
--

INSERT INTO `classes` (`cid`, `className`) VALUES
(1, 'diving 101'),
(2, 'diving 102'),
(3, 'breathing exercices'),
(4, 'fish hunting');

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
$html = '<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>';

//MYSQL Connection (change accordingly)
$mysqli = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", null, "test");

// Classes list
$classList = getClassList($mysqli);

if (!isset($_GET['submit'])) {
    $html .= '<form method="get">
        diverID: <input name="diverID"/><br/>
        class: <select name="class">';

    foreach ($classList as $key => $val) {
        $html .= '<option value="'. $key .'">'.$val.'</option>';
    }

    $html .= '</select><br/>
        time: <input type="datetime" name="time"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value ="submit"/>
    </form>';
} else {
    // Retrieve results from POST and parse them
    $diverID = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['diverID']);
    $class = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['class']);
    $time = $mysqli->escape_string($_GET['time']);

    if (canDiverRegisterForClass($mysqli, $diverID, $class, $time)) {
        if (registerDiverInClass($mysqli, $diverID, $class, $time)) {
            $html .= "<p>You were successfully registered for $classList[$class] at $time</p>";
        } else {
            var_dump(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            $html .= "<p>An error ocurred while registering you. Please contact the administrator!</p>";
        }
    } else {
        $html .= "<p>You can't register for '$classList[$class]' at $time!</p>";
    }
}
$html .= '</body></html>';
print $html;



function getClassList($mysqli)
{
    $list = array();
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM classes");
    foreach ($result->fetch_all() as $r) {
        $list[$r[0]] = $r[1];
    }
    return $list;
}

function canDiverRegisterForClass($mysqli, $diverID, $class, $time)
{
    $canRegister = true;
    $query = "SELECT class, time FROM registration WHERE diverID = '$diverID'";

    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

    if ($result && $result instanceof mysqli_result) {
        foreach ($result->fetch_all() as $r) {
            if ($r[0] == $class) {
                return false;
            }
            if ($r[1] == $time) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Error retrieveng results from database!");
    }
}

function registerDiverInClass($mysqli, $diverID, $class, $time)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO registration (diverID, class, time) VALUES ('$diverID', '$class', '$time')";
    if ($mysqli->query($query)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, almost there.  Now I get the error "Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\Pages\RegisterDiver.php on line 46"

Comment: You should pass the link of the mysqli connection. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php Check my edited answer

Comment: @Tivie nice point regarding table schemas. Its improper design.

Comment: I put all the code in that you suggested, and it still throws a bunch of errors.  I fixed a couple, but it says mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, on line 43, also mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given on line 43.  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on line 47

Comment: But yes, I know there is lots wrong with my code.  I am very new to using it.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I forgot to pass the mysql link as first parameter. Check my edit answer now.

Comment: No errors now, but nothing is registering even if there is no conflict.  The confirmation message is being displayed though.

Comment: @Tivie updated code on the original post.  I think I'm going to try and make a if/else statement that says IF (Class LIKE '.$Class.' OR Time LIKE '.$Time.'}

Comment: @Tivie I updated the code again, I'm almost there.  Just need to make it check whether or not the field being entered already exists EXACTLY LIKE the field in the database

Comment: Still is adding every time rather than saying no.

Comment: @Tivie New update, almost have it finished.  Can you see if you know how to code the last part?

Answer (score 0):

First make your select statement checking for duplicate values then insert your data, example:

```
$duplicateResult=$mysqli->query("SELECT `time`,`user`,`class` FROM `table` WHERE `time`='$time' AND `user`='$user' AND `class`='$class'");
if($duplicateResult->num_rows>=1) {
 //DUPLICATE FOUND
} else {
 //INSERT HERE
}
```

Sorry if I didn't use your table structure and queries exactly, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you are `INSERTING` rows first and then checking it for duplication. Your insert query appears first in code and after that check is being performed. Instead of that you can fire queries something like these,

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT `class` FROM $DBName WHERE `class` = '%s' OR 'time' = '%s'", mysqli_real_escape_string($DiverID,$YouSecondParam)); 
$QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);
```

then count the rows returned with [mysql_num_rows()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
if(mysql_num_rows($QueryResult)>=1){
     //dont insert. 
}else{
    // insert 
}
```

**EDIT**

Curious, aren't these  two queries,

```
$SQLstring = "INSERT INTO $TableName VALUES('$DiverID', '$Class', '$Days', '$Time')";
```

And

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO $TableName (`class`, `days`, `time`) VALUES ('".$Class.", ".$Days.", ".$Time."')");
```

are same except one with sprintf and other plain query?

**UPDATE**

I read your code. The line `If ($result = $QueryResult LIKE $Class)` must be throwing error since there's no such thing `LIKE` in php that can be used compare. Instead of that, you should use

```
if(mysql_num_rows($QueryResult)>=1){
     //dont insert. 
}else{
    // insert 
}
```

Other than that your code seems ok. One more thing, you should clean `$_GET` parameters before firing database queries. I see you've  removed `sprintf` and `mysqli_real_escape_string` . It's better to use them. Like,

```
 $Class = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnect,$_GET['class']);
 $Days = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnect,$_GET['days']);
 $Time = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnect,$_GET['time']);
 $diverID = mysqli_real_escape_string($DBConnect,$_GET['diverID']);
```

Comment: Yes they are, my code is all over the place as I have tried to implement pieces from other sources.  I am not sure what sprintf even is?

Comment: `sprintf` formats the string into desired format for you. If you are familiar with C then you would know this. Read more about sprintf here http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: Code I have now:
   $sql = sprintf("select count('x') as cnt from $DBName where `class` = '%s' OR 'time' = '%s'", mysqli_real_escape_string($Class,$Time));
    $row_dup = mysqli_fetch_assoc($QueryResult);
    if(mysql_num_rows($QueryResult)>=1)
 {
        echo "<p>You are already registered for $Class or already scheduled for $Time please go back and review your schedule.</p>";
}
else
{ $QueryResult = @mysqli_query($DBConnect, $SQLstring);}
mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli
sprintf(): Too few arguments on line 46
mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: @Tandar Error message says that, `mysql_real_escape_string()` needs one param. It cleans the data before inserting into database for safety. And you really don't need to use `count` in your query. It doesn't return result in resource array. Try the query i've stated in answer. If there already entry in table then it'll return that entry. Then you just need to count how many entries are returned. Count query is useless.

Comment: @Tandar mysql_real_escape_string() procedural style (that's what you're using) requires 2 parameter. First parameter is the mysqli link you opened, second parameter is the string to sanitize.

Comment: @Tivie It's not necessary to use second param I guess right? Because, it second param is not specified, mysql consider recently opened connection as second param implicitly. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @phazorRise In procedural style, both parameters are mandatory. Second parameter is the string to sanitize http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @phazorRise I updated the code in my post, if you don't mind looking at it? I've almost got it